# Добавление информации в блок Html-кода.

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Добрый день! У меня к вам вопрос такой: Как добавить в начало блока какую-то свою информацию?

Для добавления в конец блока можно использовать такой код:

```
$("<div><p>Ба-бах!</p></div>").appendTo(".content_wrap");
```

или

```
$('.content_wrap').append("<div><p>Проверка!</p></div>");
```

Все эти варианты добавляют лишь в конец блока информацию, а мне надо добавить перед остальной информацией в блоке добавить свою. Это возможно?

Структура пока такова допустим:

```
<div class="content_wrap">
 ...Сюда я хочу вставить свой блок...
 <div id="id1">11111111</div> 
 <div id="id2">22222222</div>
 <div id="id3">33333333</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть `append()`, значит должен быть и [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), в вашем случае попробуйте:

```
$('.content_wrap').prepend("<div><p>Проверка!</p></div>");
```

Comment: Спасибо большое), то что надо). Jquery знаю неважно, так что не знал об этом методе).